# Long Running Timer Service Pauses When Device In Deep Sleep

Tags: android, service, background-service, android-wake-lock, sleep-mode

I am developing an app that requires a long running timer service that calls a function after few minutes to send some data to the server. Its a foreground service running in the background on a separate process. I need the service running continuosly in the background until the user presses a button. But the problem I noticed is that the service pauses when device is in sleep mode which is not acceptable as the app is very time critical. Is there any way to make sure the service runs continously in the background? Is partial wake lock a good way to tackle this problem? Please help me as I'm new to android.